# check if a radio type input is selected on javascript

Tags: javascript

hy

I have an issue. I have 4 radio type input, and i want them to be checked which one is selected on my JS function to show a different panel depends on this choice. My problem is when i have to write in my function, in the parameter, how to check if my radio input has been selected or not.

This is my current function (not working):

```
function function1(){
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("btn1").is(":checked")){
        document.getElementById('div2').style.height = '200px';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('div2').style.height = '0px';
    }
    }

<label><input class="btn1" type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
<label><input class="btn1" type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
<label><input class="btn1" type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
<label><input class="btn1" type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
<button id="btn" onClick="function1()">example 1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementsByClassName()` method returns a collection of all elements

like this?

```
 function function1(){
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("btn1")[0].checked){
            alert("first selected");
        }
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("btn1")[1].checked){
            alert("second selected");
        }
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("btn1")[2].checked){
            alert("third selected");
        }
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("btn1")[3].checked){
            alert("forth selected");
        }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't work.

Comment: can you share html of buttons

Comment: ok i've edited the first one post

Comment: here document.getElementsByClassName("btn1")[0].checked is for first radio button so select first and check  for other toycan use document.getElementsByClassName("btn1")[1].checked, increase index

Comment: ok, now it works, you've been very kind and patient, thanks a lot.